# What is the name of the tree mentioned in this video?

Tags: listening

Listening to this video for about 5 seconds (it should start playing at the right time):

https://youtu.be/5tuJvei2Uw8?t=12m5s

I can understand:

> He's ordered a magnificent piece of ____; the ideal wood for bow making.

Could someone tell me what is the name of the tree/wood mentioned there?

Comment: I can confirm that it is "yew" as stated in the answer below - but your Q. is not about "English Language & Usage" as set out [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour), and I'm therefore voting to close it..

Comment: this http://www.wood-database.com/wood-articles/bow-woods/ tends to support Tajwar answer: excepted for a Madagascar specy not available in Europe until very recently, Yew seems to be the best wood for bow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not asking about "English Language & Usage" but merely for clarification of what is said in a video.

Comment: @Peque Yes. You've got your answer. The Q. is of no ongoing interest. So I suggest you should delete it. Thanks.

Comment: @TrevorD: It seems I cannot. Only a moderator could. Sorry.

Comment: Don't apologize, and don't delete it. That only encourages them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's *yew*. I'm no dendrologist, but the internet suggests that it is a slow growing and long living tree, a symbol of life and death, and highly poisonous to humans - with the exception of its berry, the *aril*. But, more important, it fits the context of the video, as yew is favourable over most wood for its properties that make it ideal for longbows.